# Почему laravel дергает Kernel при каждом запросе?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется в разработке небольшой сервис для статистики. Суть задачи на кроне - это съем позиций с яндекса.

По итогу:
идем в класс `Kernel`, метод `schedule` и пишем следующее:

```
$schedule
        ->job(new RemoverPositions)
        ->withoutOverlapping()
        ->runInBackground()
        ->everyMinute()
        ->emailOutputTo("g7-99055@yandex.ru");
```

Код работника `RemoverPositions`:

```
class RemoverPositions implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->test("construct run");
}

public function test($value)
{
    //sleep(10);
    (new Test([
        "value" => $value
    ]))->save();
}

public function __invoke()
{
    $this->test("invoke");
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->test("handle");
}
}
```

В итоге раз в минуту и при каждом запросе дергает этот метод (срабатывает почему-то только конструктор).
Как сделать так, что бы при обычных запросах (например открытие страницы) он этого не делал и всё же запускался в фоновом режиме?

P.S: В ларавеле совсем зеленый, как и в фраемворках в целом, сильно прошу не пинать)

//UPD: А так же при попытке выполнить консольно:

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Comment: А где происходит подключение класса Test в методе test

Comment: Test - это обычная моделька "на все случаи жизни"
use App\Test

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи делаются через консольные [artisan команды laravel](http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/artisan):

`php artisan make:command CommandName` после чего автоматически будет создан класс *`app/Console/Commands/CommandName.php`* в нем задается сигнатура вызова и описание команды к примеру:

```php
protected $signature = 'command:start';
protected $description = 'Моя тестовая команда';
```

В методе `handle()` логика работы программы.

```php
public function handle()
{
    echo 'РАБОТАЕТ';
}
```

Далее в *`app/Console/Kernel.php`* необходимо зарегистрировать консольную команду следующим образом

```
protected $commands = [
            ...
            Commands\CommandName::class,
    ];
```

А в методе shedule() этого же класса

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    ...
    $schedule->command(Commands\CommandName::class)->everyMinute();
}
```

После чего команда запускается каждую минуту, а если набрать в консоли `php artisan` будет выведен список всех команд среди которых созданная нами команда `command:start`, которую можно запустить следующим образом `php artisan command:start`.